# In javascript how to find value in a array of objects that has a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

```
var array [{
  machines:[{
    node: "01",
    disksize: "75",
    ram: "8"
    },
    node: "02",
    disksize: "100",
    ram: "16"
    },     
  ]
}]

let obj = objArray.find(obj => obj.disksize=== '100');
console.log(obj);
```

I tried all types of ways to get any value that I'm looking for in the are with no such luck how would this be done in javascript?

Comment: please add valid data.

Comment: What value do you want from which array?

Comment: Sorry I have tried it to many ways and copied over to this system that has internet and your right was not right.

Comment: ```var array [
  machines:{
    node: "01",
    disks:[{
      sdasize: '20',
      sdbsize: '200',
    }],
    ram: "8"
    },
    machines:{
      node: "01",
      disks:[{
        sdasize: '20',
        sdbsize: '200',
      }],
      ram: "8"
    },
]```

Comment: I want to be able to find any of the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nested array and only the inner array `machines` has the wanted object. In this case, you could iterate the outer and return the find of the inner array.

```js
var array = [{ machines: [{ node: "01", disksize: "75", ram: "8" }, { node: "02", disksize: "100", ram: "16" }] }],
    result;

array.some(({ machines }) => result = machines.find(({ disksize }) => disksize === '100'));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: great . . . :-)

Comment: What if is was different like the one below

Comment: it is simply not valid.

Comment: Sorry I copied it twice let me fix it

Comment: Is it the machines key that is making it not possible or is it my syntax

Comment: an array can not have properties in literal notation.

Answer (score 0):

What if your data is different and looks like?

```
var array = [
  machines:{
    node: "01",
    disks:[{
      sdasize: '20',
      sdbsize: '200',
    }],
    ram: "8"
    },
    machines:{
      node: "02",
      disks:[{
        sdasize: '75',
        sdbsize: '300',
      }],
      ram: "16"
    },
];
```

Comment: Would this also be the same?